# EM field from the electrons on the surface of a body and their influence to moving particles

Tags: electromagnetism, photons

Under this question [quantum field theoretic models of decoherence](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/36475/quantum-field-theoretic-models-of-decoherence) @DanielSank gave a wonderful answer. Can I implement his answer to every material body? What about I'm thinking is that on the surface of every body are electrons which make allways a EM field. And thats way particles moving not far away from the bodies shap are influent with this EM field?