# A quantum mechanical description of a polarizing filter

Tags: quantum-mechanics, photons, quantum-optics

When a single photon with polarization $\mathbf{a}$ arrives at a linear polarizing filter in the direction $\mathbf{p}$, the photon has a probability of $(\mathbf{a}\cdot\mathbf{p})^2$ to pass through the filter, while it has a probability of $1-(\mathbf{a}\cdot\mathbf{p})^2$ to be absorbed.

What does a typical quantum mechanical model of such a linear polarizing filter look like? In particular, I'm looking for how the quantized EM-field interacts with the many degrees of freedom in the filter. Also, any references to an article discussing such a model for a particular realistic polarizing filter would be appreciated.

Comment: A real absorptive polarizer may consist of many linear molecules which are ordered in parallel. Electrons can move along the length of these molecules, but not perpendicular. The same effect can be achieved with a metal grid of suitable grid size. I have no idea what it would take to formulate those systems in the language of QED, but it seems a bit like overkill for the purpose of explaining how a polarizer works, since we are not particularly interested in the quantization of the EM field inside the polarizer.

Comment: I don't know if this can be useful, but a beam splitter is in some sense a polarization filter (it deflects the radiation differently depending on the polarization), and it is extensively used in quantum optics. An example of its quantum modelization is for example [this](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0030401887900150#).

Comment: @CuriousOne: I am interested in the inside of the polarizer ;)

Comment: @yuggib: Thx the beam splitter will do fine as well.

Comment: I guess you can model the system via a quantum operation. You will describe the filter as a collection of harmonic oscillators (the phonon field) and couple it to a mode of your quantum field (in canonical quantization the EM field is a collection of oscillators as well) through a coupling of the form a b^\dagger + a^\dagger b. a is the EM field annihilation operator of the relevant mode, and b is the collective annihilation operator of the phonons modes resonating with your field.

Comment: Intuitevely tracing over the filter degrees you will be left with a master equation describing the probability of absortion. I do not any reference about this though, maybe Nielsen and Chuang or quantum optics books.

Comment: @Jasper: What do you expect to find in there, that can't be understood at the classical level?

Comment: @CuriousOne It's just for understanding foundational questions. I need a model to understand the form of the entanglement with the degrees of freedom in the polarization filter and the reduced density matrix after these degrees of freedom have been discarded. Just want a nice sensible and complete description. ;) Also just out of curiosity, since someone must make these with very high fidelities for quantum optics experiments and therefore must have thought about their quantum mechanical description.

Comment: @Jasper: So a nice classical model is not sensible? How will a QED model be "complete" unless you have a full description of every quark, Higgs, phonon, polariton, surface plasmon and magneton in there, too? OK, just kidding. The real question is, do you expect a field theoretical description of a modeled polarizer to reveal anything non-trivial that can be observed in an experiment?

Comment: @CuriousOne: Ok.. kind of snarky post.. I don't think I will find anything non-trivial but that's not the reason I should not try to understand why a beam splitter works in the first place and how efficient it can be. Also classical model does not work well with a single photon.

Comment: @Jasper: Maybe, but valid. All I am saying is that you have to pick some level of approximation, because the "complete" picture is impossible to calculate. Just curious what "high fidelity" means, in this case. The main effects of QED at the level of atomic physics are well understood, and my best bet is, that they don't concern "real" polarizers, at all. Someone correct me if I am wrong, but is Lamb shift really important to a polarization filter? That, after all, is what QED changes beyond a classical field picture in first order, isn't it?

Comment: @CuriousOne: I'm not really looking for that kind of thing.. More just a description on how entanglement between the degrees of freedom of the polarizer and the EM-field restricts the maximum purity of the resulting photon state, since after it has left the polarizer it will need to be described by a reduced density matrix. Just need a conceptual model at the moment.

Comment: The key thing to realize here is that the EM field is harmonic and usually in a coherent state. Because of this, interactions with the environment do not take the system out of the correspondance limit. For this reason, it turns out (not proving this in a comment) that you can just take the *classical* picture of loss and it's actually correct in the quantum description as well. You can see this because the interaction Hamiltonian between the photon and whatever else is $a$ on the photon, and the coherent state is an eigenstate of that operator.

Comment: On a broader level, you are essentially asking how to understand dissipation from a quantum mechanical picture. Excellent question! There is much literature about this if you Google "decoherence" or something like that, but maybe this simplified example will help you: http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/36475/quantum-field-theoretic-models-of-decoherence/122578#122578.

Comment: @DanielSank: I appreciate your clear and nice remarks, however, I don't think they hold for single photons. A single photon is definitely not a coherent state. It's okay, I got a lot out of this discussion and the reference from yuggib. I just wanted a realistic model to find what kind of form the reduced density matrix can take. In experiments the states after a polarizer are usually FAPP taken to be pure, since we neglect the entanglement with the polarizers etc. Just wanted some theoretical bounds. Thanks for the example. I'm familiar with decoherence and Caldeira-Leggett models. ;)

Comment: @DanielSank: I suspect you know this but can't resist to state it.. (please don't take it personally! ;): Decoherence is not the same as dissipation. Decoherence can take place without dissipation.

Comment: @Jasper: Regarding decoherence without dissipation, you are of course correct. At this point in my life I internalize "dissipation" as "dissipation of quantum information" which causes me to misuse language. Regarding your comment about the difference between coherent states and fock states, you are again correct, of course.